# How to pass multiple <li> element from template to Django view?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to pass list elements from template to view when I click a button.
My template looks like the following.

```
<ul id="listFrom">
  <li data-id="1"><a href="#">Element 1</a></li>
  <li data-id="2"><a href="#">Element 2</a></li>
  <li data-id="3"><a href="#">Element 3</a></li>
  <li data-id="4"><a href="#">Element 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

My aim is to pass Element 1, Element 2, Element 3, Element 4 to view.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by element? The text content? The data-id? How do you want to pass the data? A checkbox seems more suitable for passing multiple values

Comment: hi @IainShelvington please find the edited question.

Comment: You should use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple to render your choices as a list of checkboxes